# How to receive broadcast sent before activity exists?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a basic question on broadcast,

I have a broadcast receiver in code not in manifest file.
On create of the activity I create and set intent filter for broadcast.

If a service running in background sends a broadcast while the activity 
is still not started, how will this be received?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be received since it is never registered:

You need to put it *in your manifest* in order to received a broadcast when your app is not running.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent filter is not declared *in the manifest*, a matching application will not be started when the broadcast is fired by the system. 

The intent filters needs to be in the manifest for that, so your application should be sent the broadcast if it happens, in order to run at the time it is fired.

**This is documented in [Intents and Intent Filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs):**

> An intent filter is an instance of the IntentFilter class. However, since the Android system must know about the capabilities of a component before it can launch that component, intent filters are generally not set up in Java code, but in the application's manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) as  elements.